# About radical of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\alpha$ be an ideal $\ne$ 1 in a commutative ring $A$. Show that
>   $\alpha=r(\alpha)\Leftrightarrow$ $\alpha$ is an intersection of prime
>   ideals.

Here $r(\alpha)=\{x\in A|\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}:x^n\in \alpha\}$ is radical of ideal $\alpha$

I know that $R_A=\{x\in A|\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}:x^n=0\}$ is an intersection of all prime ideals in $A$, so it's easy to see that $R_A\in \alpha$, but this doesn't help ...

Please give me some suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: $r(\alpha)$ is the intersection of all prime ideals containing $\alpha$. This can be seen by finding out the inverse image of $R_{A/\alpha}$(under the natural map) and applying the fact you mentioned to $R_{A/\alpha}$.

Comment: It is easy to see that an intersection of prime ideals is a radical ideal, i.e. $\alpha=r(\alpha)$. Just take an element $x$ that has a power inside the intersection, then clearly $x$ itself will be in every prime ideal of this intersection.